# Синхронное обновление сайта без следов в консоле

Tags: протоколы

Здравствуйте, наверное мой вопрос кажется тупым, но не у кого спросить, давно голову ломаю. Раньше большинство сайты синхронно обновлялись через javaScript(xmlhttp), jquery(ajax) это можно видеть в firebug в консоле. Сейчас многие сайты обновляет страницу без следа, например блог adme, когда страницу крутишь вниз добавляется новые элементы в консоле никаких следов и еще несколько сайтов заметил. Что за прием, куда копать, чтоб научится делать так?

Спасибо за ранее.

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно *adme* – посмотрел их заглавную – **сразу грузит** текст всех статей при первой загрузке страницы: см. запрос к `http://www.adme.ru/ajax/article/best`. Но показывает только первую треть загруженных статей, и картинки грузит только для них.

По клику «Показать ещё» догружает только картинки для второй трети, и по следующему - для последней трети материалов.

Comment: разве? Зачем им лишние тексты загружать, если пользователь не нажмет эту кнопку, просто лишний груз?

Comment: когда грузятся тексты, еще и с компрессией, &plusmn;100k не заметны. Уж точно быстрее загрузить сразу чуть больше текста, чем меньше-текста, но делать ещё два HTTP запроса.